# Problems in converting string to datetime object with strptime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to convert a time string into a datetime object with strptime. The problem is that I'm getting a format error from string to datetime object.

I don't understand why this format is not appropriate for my data.

```py
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

Vent_date = np.array([b'"2018-06-28 15:00:00"', b'"2018-06-28 15:00:00"'], dtype='|S21')

dates = []
for line in Vent_date:
    line1 = line.decode('utf-8')
    dates.append(datetime.strptime(line1,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

I get:

```
ValueError: time data '"2018-06-28 15:00:00"' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: Judging from the error message, your date strings contain two sets of quotes. Are the dates in your text file quoted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you notice the error contains double quotes wrapped in single quotes. So it looks like your source data has double quotes in it which is why it is failing.

A few simple solutions:

1. Fix (remove) the quotes in your source data and use your original code
2. Strip the quotes from the string before trying to parse it:

   ```
   dates.append(datetime.strptime(line1.strip('"'),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
   ```
3. Change your date format string to look for a date containing double quotes:

   ```
   dates.append(datetime.strptime(line1,'"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"'))
   ```
4. Use Python's [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) library which may handle reading csv files better

Comment: Thank you ! I didn't see the double quotation. Just removed then with strip, and it works just fine.

Comment: One of the most important things you learn as a developer is it's almost always something tiny and stupid :).